# Problem using PulseAudio in a snap program

Tags: apparmor, octave, gnu

It appears that apparmor is preventing Gnu Octave from connecting to the Pulse audio pipe. How can I remove this restriction.

**dmesg output**

````
[10986.689501] audit: type=1400 audit(1590956219.198:4342): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="snap.octave.octave" name="/etc/pulse/client.conf" pid=16325 comm="QThread" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=0
[10986.690059] audit: type=1400 audit(1590956219.202:4343): apparmor="DENIED" operation="connect" profile="snap.octave.octave" name="/run/user/1000/pulse/native" pid=16325 comm="QThread" requested_mask="wr" denied_mask="wr" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000```
````

Comment: First list the connections via "snap connections " and see what slot refers to the pulse audio . ( Sorry I cannot test that) . and then use [snap connect](https://snapcraft.io/docs/interface-management) . Something like this : "snap connect octave:pulseaudio :pulseaudio"

Comment: Thanks! That helped me a lot.